# Swift 3 Alamofire POST with Headers Parameters, Query Parameters, and Request Body

Tags: swift, alamofire, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am faily new to Alamofire itself, so forgive me if this is a simple one. 
 I would like to post a bank account object to intuit payments using Alamofire, however I keep getting the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

The [documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/payments/bankaccounts) notes the following:

---

```
REQUEST URL
Sandbox Base URL: https://sandbox.api.intuit.com
Production Base URL: https://api.intuit.com

Operation: POST /quickbooks/v4/customers/<id>/bank-accounts
Content type: application/json
```

**Header Parameters: 
Request-Id** *required*

**Query Parameters: 
id** *required*

**Request body**

```
{
   "name": "My Checking",
   "routingNumber": "XXXXX0358",
   "accountNumber": "XXXX4534",
   "accountType": "PERSONAL_CHECKING",
   "phone": "6047296480"
}
```

---

My attempts are as follows:

```
func saveBankAccountToIntuitPayments() {
        let url = "https://api.intuit.com/quickbooks/v4/customers/" + userID! + "/bank-accounts"

        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "name": "John Doe",
            "routingNumber": "123321456",
            "accountNumber": "432123789012",
            "accountType": "PERSONAL_CHECKING",
            "phone": "55568925029"
        ]
```

**ATTEMPT 1**

```
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in
            print("running self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)")
            self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
        })
```

**ATTEMPT 2**

```
      let requestId = userID! + getTimeNow()
      let header = [ "Request-Id" : requestId ]

      Alamofire.request(url: url, method: .post, headers: header, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in
            print("running self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)")
            self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
      })
```

**ATTEMPT 3**

```
        request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: header).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in

            print("running self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)")
            self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
        })

    }
```

---

This is the code for my json parser:

```
 func parseData(JSONData: Data) {
        do {
            var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
            print("printing readable JSON (below)")
            print(readableJSON ?? "no JSON data was returned")
        } catch {
            print("errror occured (below)")
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: try this: change your print to print(response.result.value) and comment the self.parseData and see if prints the server response. I think this erros is on parsing the data

Comment: The error is regarding json parsing.

Comment: @Shabirjan I have added my json parser in case the error is there.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JoséNeto I have now tried changing my print to print(response.result.value) and commenting the self.parseData.  It returned 'nil'

Comment: @Rbar so it didn't crash and the server is sending nil. 1 - look at the statusCode -> response.response?.statusCode see the statusCode. 2 - look if the server answer is a json. 3 - look at the headers if you have passed all of them.

Comment: @JoséNeto I get `Optional(401)` from `response.response?.statusCode`.  From my searches, it looks like 401 is the error code for "Unauthorized HTTP Request."  This would make me think that the header and parameters I passed are proper but it's simply rejecting my access to the api.. any idea why?

Comment: @Rbar you have to login to make this request. Probably you have to pass Authorization and the token in the header.